# How to delete neo4j graph database

Tags: java, neo4j

I am opening the database with BatchInserter and I want after the a while to delete the database. I search but I didn't find any drop or clear function. What is the proper way to delete the database?

UPDATE:
In order to solve my problem at first I close (shutdown) the database and then I am trying to delete the database directory with the following code:

```
public void deleteRecursively(File file ) {
    if ( !file.exists() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( file.isDirectory() ) {
        for ( File child : file.listFiles() ) {
            deleteRecursively( child );
        }
    }
    if ( !file.delete() ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "Couldn't empty database." );
    }
}
```

But the directory is not always deleted successfully. I think that the problem appears when the database get big. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can delete the entire directory, or if you want to just delete the contents, you can do

```
start n=node(*)
match n-[r?]-()
delete r,n
```

in 1.9.*

and in 2.0, I guess the same:

```
match n
with n    
optional match n-[r]-()
delete r,n
```

Comment: +1 for options when the question is vague, but I think you may want to do `MATCH (n) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE r,n` in 2.0, no? Or it won't match the nodes that have no relations.

Comment: +1, deleting the directory is the way to go unless you have less than 50k nodes/rels.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to luanne's answer and go with manually deleting database directory, say "Database_name.graphdb" (If you want to delete DATABASE) or use this
`MATCH (n)

OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()

DELETE n,r`

 this will delete all your nodes and their relationships (I think, you mean this as your DATABASE).